# Preventing deadlock caused by flock

Tags: php, flock

I am trying to simulate a file writing on a busy site. I have written a following code which eventually end up freezing computer.

```
$loop = 10000;
$sleep = 500000;
$i =0;

while($i < $loop) {

    $mtime = microtime();
    $mtime = explode(" ",$mtime);
    $mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0];
    $starttime = $mtime; 

    $handler = fopen($file,"a+");
    if($handler) {
    if (flock($handler, LOCK_EX)) {
        $mtime = microtime();
        $mtime = explode(" ",$mtime);
        $mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0];
        $endtime = $mtime;
        $totaltime = ($endtime - $starttime); 

        fwrite($handler,"Script 1 took $totaltime secs\n");
    }

    flock($handler, LOCK_UN);
    fclose($handler);
}
$i++;
usleep($sleep);
}
```

I can't use LOCK_NB because it will not work on windows. The code works fine if there are less than 13 processes execute the above code at the same. How do I cope with this deadlock situation?

Comment: A deadlock between a few PHP processes shouldn't freeze your entire system. Are you sure it's a deadlock?

Comment: Yes, tried two times and end up rebooting system. I have created 40 php processes.

Comment: LOCK_NB seems to be working on Windows, despite what the docs say: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54129

Comment: I agree, that there should be no deadlock, but some waiting for the processes. If your system freezes, it could be something else. Why append to a file, and not use a database?

Comment: I am running the same code on CentOS and there is no issue with that, so it could be windows incompatibility with flock.

Comment: If you do `$starttime = microtime(TRUE)`, you'll get the time value as a simple float, saving you the explode/addition step.

Comment: Jason, did you ever figure out what was causing your apparent deadlock?

Answer (score 2):

Reading your code, I'm thinking you should move `flock($handler, LOCK_UN);` inside the `if (flock($handler, LOCK_EX)) {}` conditional block.

To figure out exactly what's getting stuck and where, I would add datestamped (and flushed, so nothing gets stuck in the output buffer) debug output both before and after each call to `flock()`, `fopen()`, `fwrite()`, and `fclose()`, and redirect the output from each script instance to its own file.

Then, after a freeze + restart you can review the end of each file and see what each script was doing when you restarted. By comparing the datestamps you should be able to see which script(s) "froze" first.

Comment: Moving the `LOCK_UN` into the `if` prevents exactly the dead lock. Being outside it might happen that processes waste the `LOCK_UN` for non existent locks and therefore stacks blocked processes.

Answer (score 1):

Hy

Try with `file_put_contents():`

`<?php`

`$file = 'file.txt';`

`$str = "some text\n";`

`file_put_contents($file, $str, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);`

`?>`

Answer (score 1):

Before you write some more php code I recommend you use the application AB (apache benchmark) that comes with apache and simulate a high load in your local host EX>

**ab -n 1000 -c 200 http://localhost/your.php**

With this you can simulate 200 concurrent users and 1000 requests.

Answer (score 0):

Try to "guard" the `LOCK_EX` with an additional `mkdir()` lock-mechanism as described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7927642/318765

Example:

```
<?php
$file = 'deadlock.txt';
$loop = 10000;
$sleep = 500000;
$i = 0;
while ($i < $loop) {
    $starttime = microtime(true);
    $handler = fopen($file, 'a+');
    if ($handler) {
        if (!file_exists($file . '_lock')) {
            if (mkdir($file . '_lock')) {
                if (flock($handler, LOCK_EX)) {
                    $endtime = microtime(true);
                    $totaltime = ($endtime - $starttime);
                    $totaltime = number_format($endtime - $starttime, 10);
                    if ($totaltime > 1) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                flock($handler, LOCK_UN);
                fclose($handler);
                rmdir($file . '_lock');
            }
        }
    }
    $i++;
    usleep($sleep);
}
?>
```

As you can see I added a `break;` to avoid the deadlock. If the scripts stops you can view into the log file.

In Linux I'm using this `mkdir()` trick without `flock()` as it is atomic. I don't know if this works in Windows, too.