# Php, var_export minifier

Tags: php, arrays

lets say I have an output of var_export:

```
return array (
  'DatabaseMySQL_settings' => 
  array (
    'absPath' => 'C:/Dolgok/WEBprogramozas/_common/plugins/_framework/core/DatabaseMySQL_settings.php',
    'namespace' => '',
    'implements' => 
    array (
    ),
    'extendsFrom' => 'Framework_setting',
    'type' => 'C',
    'isAbstract' => false,
  ),
```

instead, I want to get this:

```
return array('DatabaseMySQL_settings'=>array('absPath'=>'DatabaseMySQL_settings.php','namespace'=>'','implements'=>array(),'extendsFrom'=>'Framework_setting','type'=>'C','isAbstract'=>false,),
```

So there is no newlines and spaces. How to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove formatting of var\_export() php](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19386252) -- Or you know, just write your own var_export implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this function (`var_export_min`) in the PHP documentation comments section: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.var-export.php#54440

Answer (score 2):

If the output you want will only be used for PHP later, I recommend using [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) instead

Comment: I know, but its an extra operation :) serialize / deserialize

Comment: Indeed. But i've been reading about benchmarks and all of them point that serialize is faster.

Comment: `var_export` is way sloppier than using `serialize`, because it invariable leads to `include`ing or `eval`ing generated code. It's best to avoid doing that wherever possible. Just use `json_encode` and `json_decode`. They are fast as shit and very safe to use.

Comment: The pair [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)/[`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) is even faster than [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)/[`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php). Portability of the encoded representation of the data is a bonus.

Comment: That is true, but it depends on the later use of the output, with json encode/decode you cannot rehydrate an object of a class, you loose all reference and functionality.